# Selenium VBA (excel) to search text from Excel in web page

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am new to selenium VBA and I am using selenium web drive to find the member's name in the web page and update the information for that record.

I can search the name and click the record by using the below code:

> bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@class='x2h' and text()='Peter
> Melo']").Click

I would like to replace `Peter Melo` by using the Excel spreadsheet and `Peter Melo` is in the ActiveSheet Cell A1

So I tried to replace `Peter Melo` `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value` by using the above code but it doesn't work.

May I know how can I use the name available in Excel and search it in the Web?

Thanks in advance for any help or advice I might receive!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using
`Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value` instead of `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value` .
Range method usually used for a Range.its not the right approach to pass the single cell value.However `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value` should work. but if its not working then I assume in the active sheet it might not have any value. Can you try

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

Where Sheet1 is the Sheet where you store "PeterMello".
But this should definitely work `Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value`

Your code should be

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@class='x2h' and text()='"+Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value+"']").Click
```

or

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@class='x2h' and text()='"+Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value+"']").Click
```